# How do I solve this integral (using real analysis and residue calculus)?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, residue-calculus

The integral in question is:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(x) \, dx}{(x^2 + 16)^2}.$$

Honestly, I do not really understand residue calculus and I could really use some guidance on this problem. I get the gist of it (...I think). I just need to fill in some of the blanks.
Thank you :)

Comment: For starters, due to symmetry about $x=0$, you have $\int\limits_0^\infty=\frac12\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty$. Have you seen any worked out examples? The first two provided [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_integration#Applications_of_integral_theorems) are already quite similar to what you want to compute.

Comment: How about partial fractions on $\frac1{(x^2+16)^2}$?

Comment: Edited the integral to remove the extra $dx$ term as it is a misprint. As a note: Phys people tend to write $\int dx \, f(x)$ and math people use the readable form $\int f(x) \, dx$.

Answer (score 2):

First, notice that

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(x)}{(x^2+16)^2}dx=\frac{1}{2}\Re\left[\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{ix}}{(x^2+16)^2}dx\right]$$

Now, consider this function integrated on the arc of radius $R$ (defined by $\gamma:t\to Re^{it}$): we have

$$\left|\int_0^\pi \frac{e^{iRe^{it}}}{((Re^{it})^2+16)^2}Rie^{it}dt\right|\leq \int_0^\pi \frac{R}{|(Re^{it})^2+16|^2}dt$$

$$\leq \int_0^\pi \frac{R}{(R^2-16)^2}dt=\frac{R\pi}{(R^2-16)^2}$$

Thus, as $R$ goes to infinity

$$\lim_{R\to\infty} \int_0^\pi \frac{e^{iRe^{it}}}{((Re^{it})^2+16)^2}Rie^{it}dt=0$$

This implies that our original integral is equal to

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{iz}}{(x^2+16)^2}dx=\lim_{R\to\infty}\left[ \int_{-R}^{R}\frac{e^{ix}}{(z^2+16)^2}dz+\int_\gamma\frac{e^{iz}}{(z^2+16)^2}dz\right]$$

But these curves from $-R$ to $R$ and $\gamma$ make a closed loop (call it $\tau$). Thus, we can apply the residue theorem and say

$$\int_{-R}^{R}\frac{e^{iz}}{(z^2+16)^2}dz+\int_\gamma\frac{e^{iz}}{(z^2+16)^2}dz=\int_\tau\frac{e^{iz}}{(z^2+16)^2}dz=2\pi i \sum_{k} \text{Res}(f,a_k)$$

where

$$f(z)=\frac{e^{iz}}{(z^2+16)^2}$$

and $a_k$ are the residues of $f(z)$ inside the curve $\tau$. Now, which of the residues are actually inside this curve? Well, $(z^2+16)^2=0$ at the points $\pm 4i$. However, only one of these points is inside the curve: $4i$. Thus, our integral is equal to

$$2\pi i \sum_{k} \text{Res}(f,a_k)=2\pi i \text{Res}\left(\frac{e^{iz}}{(z^2+16)^2},4i\right)$$

Now, we can find this residue using the formula for [higher order poles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)#Limit_formula_for_higher-order_poles): since we have a pole of order $n=4$ it is

$$\text{Res}\left(\frac{e^{iz}}{(z^2+16)^2},4i\right)=\frac{1}{6}\lim_{z\to 4i}\left[\frac{d^3}{dz^3}(z-4i)^4\frac{e^{iz}}{(z^2+16)^2}\right]$$

After working through all the algebra, we find this is

$$=\frac{-5i}{256e^4}$$

Plugging this all in then gives us our final answer

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(x)}{(x^2+16)^2}=\frac{5\pi}{256e^4}$$

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using differentiation under the integral sign in place of the residue calculus.

Step 1: Use differentation under the integral sign to show for $t > 0$ that
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(tx)}{x^2+1}\,dx = \frac{\pi}{2e^t}.
$$
See Section 14 [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/analysis/diffunderint.pdf) and focus on the case $t > 0$. (The integral there is over $(-\infty,\infty)$, so divide the value there by $2$.)

Step 2: Fixing $t > 0$, make the change of variables $u = tx$ to get
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(u)}{(u^2/t^2+1)t}\,du = \frac{\pi}{2e^t}.
$$
so
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(u)}{u^2+t^2}\,du = \frac{\pi}{2te^t}.
$$
Step 3: Differentiate under the integral sign with respect to $t$ to get
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(u)}{(u^2+t^2)^2}\,du = \frac{\pi(t+1)}{4t^3e^t}.
$$
Step 4: Set $t = 4$ and the value you want pops out: $5\pi/(256e^4)$.